# I2C problem on STM32F303 processor, what is happening with SDA?

Tags: signal, stm32, i2c, stm32cubemx

I am trying to add an I2C display to my remote control drone.  I can't get the display to work.  I took the same code and copied it to a stm32f303k8 nucleo and got the display to work.  I moved the code back to the drone and tested on the STM32F303cc processor.  It doesn't work.  The signals below are form the exact same line of code going over I2c on both chips.  Well, recompiled in the cubemx framework for the different chips of course.  The yellow line is scl.  The blue line the clock.  The yellow line with the squiggles is from the drone that doesn't work.  The other 2 are from the working nucleo.  What is wrong with the signal on the drone, the stm32f303cc chip?  Why is it really squiggly.  Both have pull resistors 2.2k and 4.7k.  Specifically, why is the yellow line below, top image, split 50/50 between high and low on what looks like the acknowledgement bit?  Thanks

[image: bad communication]

[image: good communication on stm32f303k8 nucleo]

Comment: More importantly: why does SDA line not pull all the way down to ground?

Comment: I wish I knew.  Originally, on both chips, I used a total of 4 4.7k ohms resistors to pull up the voltage on the 2 lines on the 2 chips.  I then changed the resistor to a 2.2k ohms on the sda line in the top graph. No change in the appearance of the graph from the problem drone.  Even when i set the bus to 10 khz, the drone graph looked the same.  On the Nucleo, the I2C is on I2C1.  On the drone, it is on I2C2.  There are different bus speeds and clock settings also.  I don't think that should make a difference.  It looks like a tug of war between high and low on the ack

Comment: "The yellow line is scl. The blue line the clock." But "scl" *is* the clock, so I don't think you mean that :-) I think you mean that the yellow line is SDA and the blue line is SCL (the clock) - yes?

Comment: yes, the yellow line is sda/non clock

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> split 50/50 between high and low on what looks like the acknowledgement bit
>   [...]
>   It looks like a tug of war between high and low on the ack

Correct, and that means that the I<sup>2</sup>C Master didn't actually release the SDA line, for the I<sup>2</sup>C Slave to perform the Ack.

In turn, that means that the GPIO pins used for the I<sup>2</sup>C bus on the I<sup>2</sup>C Master (likely both pins, but certainly SDA) were *incorrectly configured* and left at their default of "push-pull", and not switched to "open-drain", as required for I<sup>2</sup>C operation.

That's what causes the "tug of war" as you described it, or as *glen_geek* said: "why does SDA line not pull all the way down to ground?" The answer is that SDA (and probably SCL too, but most slaves don't try to drive it) is still being *driven* (by a GPIO pin still configured as "push-pull") and not released (with passive pull-up only) as an "open-drain" pin would be.

If you are relying on STM32CubeMX to write the initialisation code, then you've either just discovered a bug in the version you are using (look for updates & errata) or else configuring it incorrectly (I don't use it, so can't tell you which setting may be wrong).

> On the Nucleo, the I2C is on I2C1. On the drone, it is on I2C2.

So the I<sup>2</sup>C ports are different between the working and non-working configurations. That could easily explain why your problem shows up only on one configuration, if the STM32CubeMX framework isn't correctly initialising I2C2 (and there have been port initialisation bugs which affect only *some* ports).

Comment: Wow, that is extremely insightful.  Thanks so much.  I bought an o scope just to see this.  I was digging into this for several weeks learning all kinds of neat stuff.  When the code was created by STM32CubeMX, it was mostly a default project for the nucleo.  The default project from cubemx for the STM32F303cc  board had i2c2 on pf0 anf pf1 pins.  I had to switch them to PA9 and Pa10 to work with the traces to those pins. this is on drone  between the display and the cpu.

Comment: I will look at the code again, i remember it was basically the same.   .. Labelled as open drain in both.  I will look at this more and see whats different.  I have to accept that one is on i2c1 and the other i2c2.  If I get this to work, the original drone code used the peripheral library , not hal.  I will ultimately have to figure how that was misconfigured/learn more about gpio config settings

Comment: @Jeffrey - I'm glad the explanation helped. :-) Getting that scope was a good idea! Re: "Labelled as open drain in both" So wherever you saw that, seems to understand that it *should* use open-drain, *but* the scope trace confirms that SDA wasn't *actually* set to open-drain. The whole purpose of I2C using open-drain drivers, is to allow *any* I2C device to *fully* pull either signal to logic low - and your Slave couldn't do that, in order to Ack. Since you have an example of a "good" I2C trace, you will know when the "problem" config is fixed, as it'll match the "good" trace (Ack fully low).